# How do i find the percentage of the elements in a list? (Python)

Tags: python, iteration, counter

I'm new to python and I'm running into an issue in my project. 
I have to read a file containing users + tasks. 
Then I should list the user names, and count the number of name were listed in the file.. grouped together. Then once I have the count, calculate the percentage of that count with the number of users listed.

file contents look like this:

```
user1, task
user2, task
user1, task
user4, task
user4, task
user1, task
```

Here is my code -

```
with open('tasks.txt', 'r') as tasks:
    for line in tasks.readlines():
        mine = line.lower().split(", ")
        for i in mine[0].split(", "):
            cnt[i] += 1
    print("\nThese are the number of tasks assigned to each user: \n" + str(cnt))
    t = sum(cnt.values())
    d = dict(cnt)
    u, v = zip(*d.items())
    print(u, v)
    for n in v:
        divide = float(n / t) * 100
        print("The users are assigned this percentage of the tasks: \n")
        print(n, divide)
```

*I would like the results to look like this:
user1 : 3, 50%
user4 : 2, 33%
user2 : 1, 16.7%

If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know

Comment: Could you add some rows in your `tasks.txt`? So we could look at the data format

Comment: What issue are you facing exactly ? From a quick glance I suppose the `cnt[i] += 1` may raise an error when the key does not exists yet; For this you could take a look at `defaultdict`

Answer (score 2):

code:

```
cnt={}
usertask = []
res = {}
with open('task.txt', 'r') as tasks:
    for line in tasks.readlines():
        mine = line.lower().split(", ")
        usertask.append(mine[0])

for i in (list(set(usertask))):
    cnt[i]=0

for user in usertask:
    cnt[user]+=1

for user,task in cnt.items():
    res[user]=task*(100/len(usertask))

print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
# read data to a list
with open('tasks.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]
```

The original way:

```
from collections import defaultdict
count = defaultdict(list)
for line in lines:
    user, task = line.split(', ')
    count[user].append(task)
for user, tasks in count.items():
    print(f'{user}: {len(tasks)*100/len(lines)}%')
```

Or the faster way is to use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
users = [line.split(', ')[0] for line in lines]
count = Counter(users)
for user, value in count.items():
    print(f'{user}: {value*100/len(lines)}%')
```

Comment: `defaultdict` only accepts factories as it's first argument, you either need to change it to `defaultdict(lambda:[])` or easier `defaultdict(list)`

Comment: Thanks. Counter feels. faster and a lighter way of doing it. Appreciate that @binh

Comment: @Plopp I'm definitely new to lambda, looking into that way now.

Comment: @trapercode If you are new to python don't bother too much with lambda now, basically what it does is creating an anonymous function (a bit like `def` but nameless). If you want to read more about it I suggest you can go through [this post](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/lambda_tutorial/). Lot's of people don't know exactly what lambda is and are just using it fine according to examples or answers on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply store all tasks of one user into a dictionary, using a `list` as value to append each incoming taks.

The amount of tasks per user is just the lenght of that list - all tasks are the sum of all lenghts:

```
fn = "d.txt"

# write demo data
with open (fn,"w") as f:
    f.write("""user1, task
user2, task
user1, task
user4, task
user4, task
user1, task""")

from collections import defaultdict

# use a dicts with values that default to list
users=defaultdict(list)

with open(fn) as tasks:
    for line in tasks:
        # split your line into 2 parts at 1st ',' - use 1st as user, 2nd as task-text
        user, task = line.strip().lower().split(", ",1)

        # append task to user, autocreates key if needed
        users[user].append(task)

    # sum all lenght values together
    total_tasks = sum(map(len,users.values()))

    # how much % equals one assigned task?
    percent_per_task = 100 / total_tasks

    for user, t in users.items():
        # output stuff
        lt = len(t)
        print(user, lt, (lt * percent_per_task),'%')
```

Output:

```
user1 3 50.0 %
user2 1 16.666666666666668 %
user4 2 33.333333333333336 %
```

Answer (score 0):

While there is a lot of merit learning how to use the basic python types, the big benefit of python from my point of view is the vast array of libraries available that solve a large number of common problems already.

If you are going to find yourself managing and transforming data files frequently in this project, consider using a library.

```py
import pandas   #import the pandas library
df = pandas.read_csv('tasks.txt', header=None, names=['user', 'task']) #read you file into a dataframe, which is a table like object
df['user'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100) #count the number of users, where the parameter normalize gives each count as a fraction, then mul (short for multiply) by 100 to turn the fraction into a percentage.
```

Comment: TBH. I'm looking into this now. This project i'm working on has a number of data type..

Comment: how do I display the results for this?

Comment: Actually nvm, I was able to have the output i wanted. I think I understand now.